# Scaling vertx server for upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)

Tags: java, nginx, vert.x

Novice here, so apologies if the question is stupid.

I have a simple application that uses Vertx as a server. The app gets a GET request, parses the URL params and logs into the file. That's it! I am running three instances of the server at different ports and using nginx to balance it.

But when I bombard my app with huge request using Jmeter, I get lot of '110: Connection timed out' error.

Deploying the verticle

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions().setEventLoopPoolSize(7).setWorkerPoolSize(18));
vertx.deployVerticle(TracRequestLoggerVerticle.class.getName(),
                new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(2).setWorker(true));
```

Running the server

```
HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer(
                new HttpServerOptions().setAcceptBacklog(Integer.MAX_VALUE).setReuseAddress(true).setTcpKeepAlive(false)
                        .setUsePooledBuffers(true).setReceiveBufferSize(4096).setSendBufferSize(1024))
                .requestHandler(router::accept);
        server.listen(HTTP_PORT);
```

Comment: Difficult to say without the verticle code.

Comment: Well I guess, u can give some standards to follow

Comment: Maybeee you get response time-out due to instantiating 18 **Worker** Verticles and it takes too long to send response. It's only my 1st guess though. Have you tried with this option `setTcpKeepAlive(true)` (i.e. set to `true` instead of `false`)?